# Sorting an Vector of Objects with std::sort

Tags: c++, sorting, object, vector

I am new at C++. I want to sort an Vector "Konten" of type vector Konto.

I've searched for a soulution and found the std::sort function. I have overloaded the operator< for the "Konto" class.
But when i try to sort the vector of Konto and compile my code i get the error message:

> Error C2678 Binary operator "=": No operator could be found that
>   accepts a "const account" left-hand operand (or proper conversion is
>   not possible) c: \ program files (x86) \ microsoft visual studio \
>   2017 \ community \ vc \ tools \ msvc \ 14.15.26726 \ include \
>   algorithm 3835

```
//KontenManager.h
#pragma once

#include "Konto.h"
#include <vector>

class Kontenmanager
{
private:
    vector<Konto> Konten;

public:
    Kontenmanager();
    ~Kontenmanager();
    string getKontenListe() const;
};

//Kontenmanager.cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "Kontenmanager.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>


Kontenmanager::Kontenmanager()
{
}


Kontenmanager::~Kontenmanager()
{
}


string Kontenmanager::getKontenListe() const
{
    stringstream out;
    sort(Konten.begin(), Konten.end());            //<----------- Here is my problem

//do some stuff

}

//Konto.h
#pragma once

#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Konto
{
private:
    int kontoNr;
    double saldo;
    string inhaber;
    int pin;

public:
    Konto(int Kontonummer, string inhaber, int pin);
    ~Konto();
    int getKontonummer() const;
};

bool operator<(const Konto &k1, const Konto &k2);
bool operator==(const Konto &k1, const Konto &k2);

//Konto.cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "Konto.h"


Konto::Konto(int Kontonummer, string inhaber, int pin) :kontoNr(Kontonummer)
{
    this->kontoNr = Kontonummer;
    this->inhaber = inhaber;
    this->pin = pin;
    this->saldo = 0.0;
}


Konto::~Konto()
{
}

int Konto::getKontonummer() const
{
    return kontoNr;
}

bool operator<(const Konto &k1, const Konto &k2)
{
    return k1.getKontonummer() < k2.getKontonummer();
}

bool operator==(const Konto &k1, const Konto &k2)
{
    return k1.getKontonummer() == k2.getKontonummer();
}
```

Comment: Replace `const int kontoNr;` with `int kontoNr;` and remove `const` qualifier for `getKontenListe`.

Comment: The reason to close the question is not appropriate at all, the desired behavior is obvious : to compile without error, and we have all to reproduce the problem

Comment: @drescherjm, first, `Konto` is not assignable, second, in `getKontenListe` you can't change `Konten`.

Comment: i've changed the const attribute but still the same problem

Comment: @bruno There is no MCVE in this question, though. This is quite far from minimal, actually.

Comment: @BaummitAugen how I was able to reproduce the problem then ? ;-)

Comment: @SSJ I can compile and run removing the _const_

Comment: @bruno How does you being able to find the problem in this code proof it's minimal?

Comment: @BaummitAugen not sure to understand you, I just get the code, add a call to sort and tried to compile, that is all

Comment: @SSJ what error do you have after removing the _const_ ?

Comment: still the same... you mean the cont bevor int kontoNr right?

Comment: @SSJ yes, the field must not be const. I cannot put an answer with the code because the question is closed ^^

Comment: ahh i overread the const for the getKontenListe.. thank you very much now it is working

Comment: @bruno [This](https://wandbox.org/permlink/k6V0DtV0qWLbCHUg) would have been a minimal example for the `const` issue, for starters.

Comment: @SSJ ok, happy coding

Comment: @BaummitAugen I copied like 50 lines from the question to have the class and operations definitions and add 10 lines to have a main filling a vector sort and write it, really I do not understand you, but whatever, the OP got the correction, this is the main, have a good continuation

Comment: maybe one more question... this was my first question on this forum. schould i delete the question or can i set in in solved?

Comment: @SSJ you cannot set it solved because for that you need to accept an answer and there is no answer. If you want to can delete it, or you can wait it is reopen. But if reopen it can be closed again for simple typo error

Comment: This question can be deleted as it won't be reopened. This question does not contain a mcve. A mcve is code, that can be copied without change and reproduces the problem. Your code has to be modified to work.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an error in Visual Studio, you can press **F1** on your computer keyboard to get help on that error.

Also any developer should know about **google.com** Type **C2678** in the search box and press enter.

Here is the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2678?view=vs-2019

Answer: Remove extra `const` specifier as mentionned by others.